# Penetrating Vision, TK, and choke

Tags: psionics, attack, gurps-4e

My character has Penetrating Vision 1 and Telekinesis 10. How would I handle the following situations?

1. Could I use TK to squeeze the internal organs of an opponent to do damage, or would I have to buy some variation of crushing attack (as is done in GURPS Psionic Powers)? If I can use TK, how would the attack and damage be resolved and would I still need a successful grapple first?
2. If I can do that, could I choke the opponent (to keep them from speaking) by attacking their wind pipe (as the selected internal organ) directly? If so, would this make it harder for the opponent to defend against or escape since the TK "hands" are now essentially inaccessible?
3. Lastly, if I also have Compartmentalized Mind 1, could I use both concentrate maneuvers to perform the same attack in tandem, and how would I handle that - as a cooperation bonus, add the two strength ratings together, resolve them separately, or something else?

I am using the abilities out of the main book as, even though they are more expensive, they don't require rolling against a bunch of skills to do things, and TK is way more flexible. So while GURPS Psionic Powers is an allowed resource, I'd prefer answers that focus on the Advantages as listed in Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A general principle of GURPS [rules interpretation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113134/how-are-gurps-rules-interpreted/113135#113135) is that you have to *buy* your effects, not achieve them by creative rules interpretation. So yes, you do need to buy a crushing attack, as demonstrated in ***Psionic Powers***. However, it doesn't have to be the *same design* as ***Psionic Powers***, there's lots of scope for variation.

   Figuring out exactly what you want to buy and answering that isn't well-suited to the Stack Exchange question-and-answer format. The [GURPS forum](http://forums.sjgames.com/forumdisplay.php?f=13) at Steve Jackson Games has plenty of people who like to do this stuff, and will be willing to help.
2. With an appropriately designed attack, you could ensure that your target got no defence roll against the initial attack, unless they had some ability to detect it. Grappling and choking is certainly possible.
3. I'm not an expert on Compartmentalised Mind and find it confusing. The GURPS forum can help with that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping to avoid having to create yet another forum account, but it looks like it might be unavoidable.