# GURPS Psionics - TK Bullet Damage

Tags: gurps-4e

I'm new to GURPS, and I'm attempting to put together a Psychokinetics-based character. I've found the TK Bullet ability (Psionic Powers 4e, pg.53) and have put 5 points into it.

However, I'm confused about how to calculate the damage for the ability. In the second paragraph of its description, it states:

> Damage is 1d-1 pi per level of TK bullet;

Does this imply that, if I have 5 levels in the ability, it does 5d-5? That seems quite high. That makes me think, do further levels move the damage up some sort of scale like the one used for ST attacks?

[image]

What is the actual damage of this ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the page more closely (my fault for not doing my due diligence), there is a section next to the TK Bullet power that describes its cost calculation (*Innate Attacks and Partial Dice*). In this section, there is a sentence that describes the damage of a TK Bullet 8:

> Example: Each level of TK Bullet is built on Piercing Attack 1d-1...
> However, a teke with TK Bullet 8 (Piercing
> Attack 8d-8)...

This indicates that the actual damage of a TK Bullet 5 ability really is 5d-5.

Comment: I was considering deleting the question after finding the answer so quickly, but I'll be leaving this up in case anyone has the same question in the future.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. GURPS has an assumption that the GM will say "No" at some point as the power is bought up. There's a question about GURPS rules interpretation [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113134/how-are-gurps-rules-interpreted). There was a PC with TK Bullet at level 7 or 8 in the last long campaign I ran. It was the party's largest single attack, and it was adequate for everything they found themselves forced to fight.